# Can I write 'RewriteCond' using 'functions.php'?

Tags: php, functions, rewrite-rules, security, mod-rewrite

I want to add 'rewrite condition' in **.htcaccess** but unfortunately I don't have access of that.
Can I write conditions in functions.php ? If yes, how to achieve that ?
I want to add these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.{1000,}$
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/load-scripts\.php$ - [F]
```

Comment: _Aside:_ The directives as posted don't quite make sense. The solitary `f` at the end should be `[F]`. Is the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ intentionally uppercase?

Comment: ref- https://hackerone.com/reports/925425

Comment: Ok, but that rule is certainly wrong. It should read `RewriteRule ^wp-admin/load-scripts\.php$ - [NC,F]`. The rule as written (all uppercase and no `NC` flag) would fail to match the request it is trying to block. The `NC` flag would be required if you are running this on a Windows platform. And the lone `f` at the end would trigger an immediate 500 Internal Server Error (since it's entirely invalid syntax).

Comment: ok, thanks!!
do u know how to achieve that via functions or any php code? I have edited my code

Comment: I'm not sure sorry. Whatever code you add, it needs to still edit the `.htaccess` file. If you don't have permission to edit `.htaccess` (or there is no `.htaccess`) file then this isn't going to be possible. (Has this vulnerability not already been "fixed" in `load-scripts.php`?)

Comment: @Ricky can you explain what exactly do you mean by "I don't have access of that"? You can't edit the file via FTP/cPanel? Is the file writable from PHP scripts?

Comment: @SallyCJ Hey, no! my client has given only WP Dashboard access :( issue is listed here https://hackerone.com/reports/925425

Comment: Well, if you're able to manage (install & activate) plugins on the site, then you could try using a plugin (like [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-htaccess-editor/)) which can help you edit the `.htaccess` file. But if the file is not writable from PHP scripts, then you'll have to ask the client for an access to FTP or the hosting's file manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-htaccess-editor/, if you are not willing to use any plugin, understand the code and implement in functions.php or your own custom plugin.
cheers.